# String parsing: Extracting the filename from a URL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is a link I have in a column of a table:

```
http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/browse/etm/1/11/2000/LE70010112000130KIS00.jpg
```

There are like 1000's of rows like this.

- Is it possible to extract the FileName like `LE70010112000130KIS00` (without the path and filename extension) and put it in another column?

I am new to SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this code to extract the FileName with Extension.

```
UPDATE TableName set ColumnName= right(Image_Link, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(ColumnName) + '/') - 1)
```

And this code to extract and update only FileName

```
UPDATE TableName  SET ColumnName= REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(ColumnName),CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(ColumnName)) + 1, 999))
```