# Extract Database Name From String

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, string-manipulation

In a database we have the full file path for a database field type is `nvarchar(255)` and structure/data would look like this:

```
M:\Blue\Red\Green\Folder\Pink\Purple\Database1.accdb
M:\Blue\Red\Orange\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Size\Small\Large\DbTest1232323Test.accdb
```

My question is, how can I extract only the database name – pull only this out:

- Database1.accdb
- DbTest1232323Test.accdb

Since the name of the database can vary, I can't use just a `RIGHT()` function.

Is there a way I can somehow use a wildcard in conjunction with `RIGHT()` to say, "Pull everything to the right of the last `\`"?

Comment: I guess you could use the answer here and replace slash with backslash in the code example. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127796/15356

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do it.  You'll want the last column (FileName_Only).

```
SELECT f.physical_name,
    REVERSE(f.physical_name) AS physical_name_Reversed,
    CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(f.physical_name)) AS First_Backslash_When_Reversed,
    LEFT(REVERSE(f.physical_name), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(f.physical_name)) - 1) AS FileName_Only_Reversed,
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(f.physical_name), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(f.physical_name)) - 1)) AS FileName_Only
FROM sys.database_files f
```

Here's another option. The code is a bit leaner:

```
SELECT 
    f.physical_name,
    REVERSE(f.physical_name) AS physical_name_Reversed,
    CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(f.physical_name)) AS First_Backslash_When_Reversed,
    RIGHT(f.physical_name, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(f.physical_name)) - 1) AS FileName_Only
FROM sys.database_files f
```